# NuGet error when trying to install EEPlus

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I get following error when trying to install EEPlus. Using .net framework 4.5. Was trying to use PM console but I get error: 'EPPlus' already has a dependency defined for 'EPPlus.Interfaces'. Can someone help?